# how to get start and end of a leaflet slider

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i have a leaflet slider with range, i want to have two  elements holding the start and end date of each of the handles, like in [here](http://nyc.crashmapper.com/11/8/14/2/standard/collisions/2/10/40.644/-73.887), any idea how to do this.
this is how i tried to modify the slider javascript file

```js
L.Control.SliderControl = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topright',
        layers: null,
        timeAttribute: 'time',
        isEpoch: false,     // whether the time attribute is seconds elapsed from epoch
        startTimeIdx: 0,    // where to start looking for a timestring
        timeStrLength: 19,  // the size of  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - if millis are present this will be larger
        maxValue: -1,
        minValue: 0,
        showAllOnStart: false,
        markers: null,
        range: false,
        follow: false,
        alwaysShowDate : false,
        rezoom: null
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
        this._layer = this.options.layer;

    },

    extractTimestamp: function(time, options) {
        if (options.isEpoch) {
            time = (new Date(parseInt(time))).toString(); // this is local time
        }
        return time.substr(options.startTimeIdx, options.startTimeIdx + options.timeStrLength);
    },

    setPosition: function (position) {
        var map = this._map;

        if (map) {
            map.removeControl(this);
        }

        this.options.position = position;

        if (map) {
            map.addControl(this);
        }
        this.startSlider();
        return this;
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        this.options.map = map;

        // Create a control sliderContainer with a jquery ui slider
        var sliderContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'slider', this._container);
        $(sliderContainer).append('<center><div id="leaflet-slider" style="width:280px; box-shadow: rgba(0,0,10,1) 1px 2px 50px;background-color:2E2E1F" ><div  class="ui-slider-handle"></div><div id="slider-timestamp" style="width:280px; margin-top:13px; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; border-radius:5px;"></div></div></center>');
  //Prevent map panning/zooming while using the slider
        $(sliderContainer).mousedown(function () {
            map.dragging.disable();
        });
        $(document).mouseup(function () {
            map.dragging.enable();
            //Hide the slider timestamp if not range and option alwaysShowDate is set on false
            if (options.range || !options.alwaysShowDate) {
                $('#slider-timestamp').html('');
            }
        });

        var options = this.options;
        this.options.markers = [];

        //If a layer has been provided: calculate the min and max values for the slider
        if (this._layer) {
            var index_temp = 0;
            this._layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                options.markers[index_temp] = layer;
                ++index_temp;
            });
            options.maxValue = index_temp - 1;
            this.options = options;
        } else {
            console.log("Error: You have to specify a layer via new SliderControl({layer: your_layer});");
        }
        return sliderContainer;
    },

    onRemove: function (map) {
        //Delete all markers which where added via the slider and remove the slider div
        for (i = this.options.minValue; i < this.options.maxValue; i++) {
            map.removeLayer(this.options.markers[i]);
        }
        $('#leaflet-slider').remove();
    },

    startSlider: function () {
        _options = this.options;
        _extractTimestamp = this.extractTimestamp
        var index_start = _options.minValue;
        if(_options.showAllOnStart){
            index_start = _options.maxValue;
            if(_options.range) _options.values = [_options.minValue,_options.maxValue];
            else _options.value = _options.maxValue;
        }
        $("#leaflet-slider").slider({
            range: _options.range,
            value: _options.value,
            values: _options.values,
            min: _options.minValue,
            max: _options.maxValue,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (e, ui) {
                var map = _options.map;
                var fg = L.featureGroup();
                if(!!_options.markers[ui.value]) {
                    // If there is no time property, this line has to be removed (or exchanged with a different property)
                    if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature !== undefined) {
                        if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties[_options.f ]){
                            if(_options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(
                                _extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
                        }else {
                            console.error("Time property "+ _options.timeAttribute +" not found in data");
                        }
                    }else {
                        // set by leaflet Vector Layers
                        if(_options.markers [ui.value].options[_options.timeAttribute]){
                            if(_options.markers[ui.value]){ $('#slider-timestamp').html(
                                _extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.value].options[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
        $('#start').html($("#slider-timestamp").html());
       $('#end').html(
                                _extractTimestamp(_options.markers[ui.value].options[_options.timeAttribute], _options));}
        
                        }else {
                            console.error("Time property "+ _options.timeAttribute +" not found in data");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    var i;
                    // clear markers
                    for (i = _options.minValue; i <= _options.maxValue; i++) {
                        if(_options.markers[i]) map.removeLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                    }
                    if(_options.range){
                        // jquery ui using range
                        for (i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++){
                           if(_options.markers[i]) {
                               map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                               fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                           }
                        }
                    }else if(_options.follow){
                        for (i = ui.value - _options.follow + 1; i <= ui.value ; i++) {
                            if(_options.markers[i]) {
                                map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                                fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        for (i = _options.minValue; i <= ui.value ; i++) {
                            if(_options.markers[i]) {
                                map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                                fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                if(_options.rezoom) {
                    map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds(), {
                        maxZoom: _options.rezoom
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        if (!_options.range && _options.alwaysShowDate) {
            $('#slider-timestamp').html(_extractTimeStamp(_options.markers[index_start].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
        }
        for (i = _options.minValue; i <= index_start; i++) {
            _options.map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
        }
  
    }
});

L.control.sliderControl = function (options) {
 $('span').show();
    return new L.Control.SliderControl(options);
};
```

the original script is [Dwilhelm89's slider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through the code for that example page gives some idea of how they are achieving the effect you're looking for, so most of this answer is a rough copy of what they've done there.

The main thing you need to do is create some divs within the sliderContainer where you can put the labels. If you do it at the same time you create the slider div, it would look like this:

`$(sliderContainer).append('<div id="slider-min"></div><div id="leaflet-slider" style="width:280px; inline-block; margin: 0 5px 0 5px;"></div><div id="slider-max"></div><div id="slider-current"><span class="start-time"></span>-<span class="end-time"></span></div>');`

where `slider-min` and `slider-max` are the divs for labels at the beginning and the end of the slider, respectively, and `slider-current` is the div for the range labels (`start-time` and `end-time`) that change as you move the slider.

Populating `slider-min` and `slider-max` can be done within the onAdd function, which would look like this:

```
$('#slider-min', sliderContainer).html(this.options.markers[this.options.minValue].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
$('#slider-max', sliderContainer).html(this.options.markers[this.options.maxValue].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
```

Initializing the `start-time` and `end-time` values can also be done within onAdd, but because they will need to be updated, it's useful to assign them some names first and populate them with a function:

```
this.$currentStartDiv = $('#slider-current .start-time', sliderContainer);
this.$currentEndDiv = $('#slider-current .end-time', sliderContainer);
this._updateCurrentDiv(0,0);
```

where `_updateCurrentDiv` is defined at the main level of the LeafletSlider function (i.e., outside of onAdd):

```
_updateCurrentDiv: function (startIdx, endIdx) {
this.$currentStartDiv.html(this.options.markers[startIdx].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
        this.$currentEndDiv.html(this.options.markers[endIdx].feature.properties[this.options.timeAttribute]);
},
```

For changing labels dynamically, this function can be referred to within the slide function, though for scoping reasons that I don't fully understand, `this` needs to be re-assigned to a different variable (i.e. `self = this`) first. Within the slider function, `_updateCurrentDiv`would be called like this:

```
if (_options.range) {
    // jquery ui using range
    for (i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++) {
        if (_options.markers[i]) {
            map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
            fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
        }
    }
    self._updateCurrentDiv(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);
}
```

That pretty much covers all the functionality. The aesthetics can be taken care of with css, the two main things being that the slider and the min and max divs (if you want all of those lined up neatly) should be styled as `display: inline-block`, so that they don't get bumped to separate lines, and the `slider-current` div (if you want the dynamic labels outside the white control box boundary) should be styled as `position: absolute` and `left: 420px` (or whatever displacement works for your purposes).

A working example of all this is cobbled together in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/mos9Lr5v/

Comment: I have this problem while trying to modify as your code : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined